# Permissions to create certificate

Tags: sql-server, permissions, certificate

Is there a way to grant a user permissions to create certificate in SQL Server?

Comment: Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-certificate-permissions-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

There is a `CREATE CERTIFICATE` permission:

```
GRANT CREATE CERTIFICATE TO [user_or_role_name];
```

Here is a simple test:

```
USE [tempdb];

CREATE USER [t] WITHOUT LOGIN;

EXECUTE AS USER = 't';

PRINT 'Before GRANT:';
CREATE CERTIFICATE [tt] WITH SUBJECT = 'test';

REVERT;

GRANT CREATE CERTIFICATE TO [t];

EXECUTE AS USER = 't';

PRINT 'After GRANT:';
CREATE CERTIFICATE [tt] WITH SUBJECT = 'test';

REVERT;

DROP USER [t];
```

Which returns (in the "Messages" tab):

> Before GRANT:
>   Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   User does not have permission to perform this action.
>   After GRANT:
>   Msg 15581, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.